# Javascript true condition not being executed

Tags: javascript, php

True condition is never executed, instead the false condition is always executed. I cant seem it find what exactly I'm doing wrong.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var userEmail = $('input#userEmail').val();
  $("#email-submit").click(function(){
    //False condition
    if(!validateEmail(userEmail)) { 
      $('#emailErrors').text("Enter a valid Email");
    }
    //true conidition
    if(validateEmail(userEmail)) { 
      alert("true");
      $.post('includes/loginFunction.php', {userEmail: userEmail}, function (data){
        $('#emailErrors').text(data);
      });
    }
  });
});
function validateEmail($email) {
   var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
   return emailReg.test( $email );
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Not the source of your problem, but instead of checking the email twice with 2 `if` conditions, you should just use `else`

Comment: the function `validateEmail` works, what are your values that you're testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/uf6Ld70f/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#email-submit").click(function () {
        var userEmail = $('input#userEmail').val();
        //true conidition
        if (validateEmail(userEmail)) {
            alert("true");
            $.post('includes/loginFunction.php', {
                userEmail: userEmail
            }, function (data) {
                $('#emailErrors').text(data);
            });
        // false
        }else{
            $('#emailErrors').text("Enter a valid Email");
        }
    });
});

function validateEmail($email) {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return emailReg.test($email);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to inspect `input#userEmail` *within* your click handler. Otherwise, you have only stored what the value of the input was when the `$(document).ready()` callback was executed.

```
$("#email-submit").click(function(){
  var userEmail = $('input#userEmail').val();

  if (!validateEmail(userEmail)) { 
    $('#emailErrors').text("Enter a valid Email");
  } else {
    // true condition
  }
}
```

You also, as per above, can use `else` instead of calling `validateEmail` twice.

And further, in your `validateEmail` function, you're declaring the parameter `$email`. Usually, the convention for prefixing a `$` before a variable is when you're caching a jQuery (or other library) object. You should probably switch this to simply `email`.